# Bitwise AND with 0 is unreachable in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I want to check if the LSB is 0.

`if(some_size_t & 1){}` works fine

But why is `if(some_size_t & 0){//This parts is unreachable}` never reachable?

Comment: because any number ANDed with 0 is always 0, it is like multiplication by 0, so condition is always false

Comment: if you want to check that LSB is 0, you need to use `if (some_size & 1 == 0)`

Comment: @IłyaBursov: No, you need to use `if ((some_size & 1) == 0)`. Otherwise it is parsed as `if (some_size & (1 == 0))`.

Comment: Or just use `!(some_size_t & 1)`. But all these (including mine) are *answers* rather than comments so should probably be posted as such :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in order to ever get the value `1` i.e. `true` both operands for the logical and bitwise & i.e. AND operator have to be `1`. Its so called truth table is

```
op1 | op2 | op1 AND op2
=====================
0   | 0   | 0
1   | 0   | 0
0   | 1   | 0
1   | 1   | 1
```

Because your value, e.g. op2, `0` has only zeros, no ones, you will always get only zeros as a result, no matter the other operand. And `0` will evaluate to false. It's what we call a contradiction in logic, often noted with a up side down T or `\bot` in latex.

As then the `if` condition is always `false`, the code in its body will never be executed, i.e. is *unreachable*.